# text post and image post with different 'main-wrapper' size

Tags: html, css, blogger

text post and image post with different 'main-wrapper' size.

• here is a post with picture - (SOLVED)

• and here is a post with text only - (SOLVED)

I have set the side-bar: 25%
and the main-wrapper: 75%
but why is this happening? 
i didn't notice this when I put this code `.post-body img { width: 1000px; height:500px;  }` maybe this is the reason? I need it to resize all future posts to maximum width (75%).

How do I fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main-wrapper` is ok, but you don't have any width on `Blog1` id, so the width is set by the content. Quick fix would be to add width to `Blog1` as well as padding:

```
#Blog1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```